# How to get the address of a cell

Tags: c#

I'm trying to find the address of a cell in a xlsx file using c#, but i can't find a right solution for it.

```
using IronXL;
var workbook = IronXL.WorkBook.Load("email list.xlsx");
var sheet = workbook.WorkSheets.First();
var cells = sheet["A1:C494"];
foreach(var cell in cells)
{
     Console.WriteLine(cell.Value);
     //print cell adress
}
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: The docs say there's a property called [`AddressString`](https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/excel/object-reference/api/IronXL.Cell.html#IronXL_Cell_AddressString). Have you tried that?

Comment: I have seen the doc, but i am a begginer(second day)and i don't know how to code it to make that work. Thank you

Comment: Similarly to `cell.Value`, try `cell.AddressString`

Comment: When reading the docs takes too much time, you can always look at the examples (https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/excel/examples/read-excel/)